# rename a column starting with @ in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I add some shape files in Postgres and there is a column which is named `@id`. I wanted to select this column but there is a syntax error because of `@`.

I have many tables which containing this field, how can I change it in not manually way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *can* select `@id` by either using the unicode character or by surrounding the column name with double-quotes:

```
SELECT U&"\0040id" FROM tablename;
SELECT "@id" FROM tablename;
```

You can use either method to rename the column as well:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME COLUMN U&"\0040id" to "id";
ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME COLUMN "@id" to "id";
```

Answer (score 1):

The principle is the same, you just have to make sure you have the name enclosed in double quotes.

```
ALTER TABLE "some_table"
    RENAME COLUMN "old_name" TO "new_name";
```